# Definition of SQUARE ML (㎖)

Tags: notation, definition, physics

This is a very simple thing, I suppose, I'm having hard time to find out, what is the meaning of Square ML (㎖) symbol? Square MiLe, Square MilliLiter, Square Maximum Likelihood, or totally something else?

I can find these symbols belonging to the physical symbol set in unicode set starting from:

```
0x3371  13169   SQUARE HPA  ㍱
```

and going to:

```
0x33DD  13277   SQUARE WB   ㏝
```

http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html

Along ML are:

```
0x3395  13205   SQUARE MU L ㎕
0x3396  13206   SQUARE ML   ㎖
0x3397  13207   SQUARE DL   ㎗
0x3398  13208   SQUARE KL   ㎘
```

And yes, this seems to be more of physics topic, not that much mathematics...

Comment: There is no standard meaning. What is intended should be evident from the context that you chose not to provide.

Comment: Thats fair enought!

Comment: :-) To be honest, of the alternatives you listed I can only think of square mile actually appearing. But, I would think *sq mi* is "standard" abbreviation of that.

Comment: @Jyrki The symbol ㎖ appears in the [CJK compatability block](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/cjk_compatibility/utf8test.htm) because it is a character used in Japanese for a unit, like essentially everything else in that block. It unambiguously means milliliter, and that is clearly identified on sites like [Japanese wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB#.E7.AC.A6.E5.8F.B7.E4.BD.8D.E7.BD.AE). The "square" [just refers to the fact that the letters are combined to fit in a square ◻](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3396/index.htm).

Comment: Thanks, @MarkS. Reopening, as there seems to be interest. I am not convinced that this is on-topic because it then looks like it is more about character encoding and less about math. But I'm not gonna stand in the way either.

Comment: I dont know how it turn out to look to others, but for me it is about the definition of the symbol, that I thought was related to either mathematics or physics. I think I got enough information about it now. I could accept an answer if there was one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This post will use a lot of unicode characters that may not display properly in some environments.

---

The characters in the [CJK Compatability block](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/cjk_compatibility/utf8test.htm) are mostly symbols for units used in Japanese, with some crossover into other languages like Chinese and Korean. Most of them have a name in unicode with "SQUARE" (as in [SQUARE ML](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3396/index.htm)) because the character is made from multiple symbols designed to fit the square space that a character would fit in for proper Chinese/Japanese/Korean typesetting. For example, compare the spacing of "c""m" vs. "cm" in this string:
 三ｃｍ三cm因.

㎖ means milliliter, and this meaning is shown on the [Japanese](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB#.E7.AC.A6.E5.8F.B7.E4.BD.8D.E7.BD.AE) and [Korean](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%A6%AC%ED%84%B0) wikipedia pages for "liter". You can also see is referenced in math courses. For example, a middle school math student is asking about the relationship between ㎤ (a single character for $\mathrm{cm}^3$) and ㎖ [here](http://lineq.jp/q/56963558).

There are many other units and related symbols in the CJK Compatability block, including ㏑ for $\ln$, ㏒ for $\log$, ㎯ ($\mathrm{rad}/\mathrm{s}^2$) for the SI measure of angular acceleration, ㌫ for "percent", and ㌦ for "dollar(s)", etc. The last two are written in [Japanese phonetic characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana).